Is there a way to automatically exclude parts of the output in the TikZ plot path where the dimensions are too large?
Is there a way to automatically exclude parts of the output in the TikZ plot path where the dimensions are too large? I want to make an animation where some points traverse over infinity.
In pgfplots there is the restrict x to domain=n:m, but I cannot seem to find an equivalent in TikZ.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[domain=-5:5,smooth,samples=10,variable=\Vx,blue] plot ({\Vx},{1/\Vx});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

Comment out the samples parameter and it will fail.


You can set up a clipping rectangle.  I assume plot uses nromal coordinates (unike data visualization).  You will still get a wrap-around at 0.

That's what I've been using for most things, though the division by zero error seems to outweigh this measure. I guess what I can do it plot several different functions that have domains which vary by a parameter. I guess doing the actual math would allow me to get better results.

If you use an even number of samples, you won't actually divide by zero.  Not sure if clipped data affects the bounding box though.  The easy solution is to use two plots and simply avoid zero.

TikZ does not directly have the ability to throw away point that you do not like. -but if you use gnuplot (needs gnuplot installed and compiled with --shell-escape/write18) a table is created and this table can leave out points. The options to do this is range (and xrange+yrange for parametric plots) like this:
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[red] (-5,-3) rectangle (5,3);
\draw[blue] plot[domain=-5:5, samples=100, id=temp, range=-3:3, smooth] function{1/x};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


