Infinite plot value cuts the plot at that point
For this minimal example, I follow this formula for the red line:

Image source
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
%for plotting
 \usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xlabel={Frequency (Hz)},
        xmin=1, xmax=1e12,  % Frequency range from 1 Hz to 1 GHz
        ymin=1e-6, ymax=1e3,    % Adjust the range for reactance
        grid=both,
        xmode=log,  % Logarithmic scale for frequency axis
        ymode=log,  % Logarithmic scale for reactance axis
        width=140mm, % Adjust the width to fit the plot within the page
        height=12cm,
        thick,
        y label style={
            at={(axis description cs:0.2,0.5)},% Position inside the plot
            color=black,% Optional: change color
        },
    ]
    % Plotting the inductive reactance X_L = 2πfL
    \addplot[color=blue, domain=1:1e12, samples=500] 
    {1/ (1/(2*pi*x*1e-6) +(2*pi*x*1e-9) )};%Blue: 1uH, 1nF 
    \addplot[color=red, domain=1:1e12, samples=500] 
    {1/ (1/(2*pi*x*1e-6) -(2*pi*x*1e-9) )};%Red: 1uH, 1nF   
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

Which shows me this output:

I would expect the red plot to be infinite at the point where it stops plotting, but then it should come down again like this:

Same image source
The red plot is cut due to the infinite value at that point, probably.
Q1) Is there a way to make latex calculate the rest of the red plot?
Q2) Or is there a way to put a maximum cap on the red plot values, so that if the result/plot is more than the cap value, it will stay at cap value.
*(I put the Blue plot there as a visual example that the red plot can continue even more to the right).

This strikes me as though it would be a significantly difficult undertaking to automate generally for all functions. I actually asked a similar question here  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/722035/is-there-a-way-to-automatically-exclude-parts-of-the-output-in-the-tikz-plot-pat. The best approach I currently have is to either do it manually by plotting separate domain ranges to exclude the asymptotes, or take an algebraic approach to do the same thing.

it seems as if unbounded coords=jump or restrict y to domain*=<min>:<max> ought to do something here, but I can't make that work at all.@Jasper your linked question suggests you had it working for pgfplots and the problem was only in the tikz case. since this case uses pgfplots, do you know how to do it here?

@cfr You know, it's been a while since I've used pgfplots and I was going based off of memory, so it's possible I may have misspoke. Let me see if I can get an example working for you.

@cfr Yep, the syntax works. I have a MWE where I plot 1/x in pgfplots, and it automatically truncates it. I use \addplot[restrict y to domain=-5:5] {1/x}; in an axis environment.

@Jasper thanks. so maybe the OP can use something similar. (I tried to get it to work quickly-ish, but I don't use pgfplots very often.)

@ChristianVasilis when I try plotting the red function separately for a domain right of the asymptote (e.g. domain=1e8:1e12), and nothing seems to show up. the restrict y to domain=<min>:<max> syntax should work if you can get the \addplot to work on the right of the asymptote.

@Jasper restrict y to domain=-100:5 does stop the function from plotting its "infinite" point. But I cannot make it work on the right side only, using domain=1e8:1e12 for example. It looks like it still starts to calculate from 0 and tries to calculate the infinite point and it fails before reaching the domain I set to it so it plots nothing. The blue plot does not have this issue though, domain=1e8:1e12 works fine on the blue plot.

You can not plot negative values on a logarithmic scale
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
width=14cm, height=12cm,
xlabel={Frequency (Hz)},
xmin=1, xmax=1e12,
%ymin=1e-6, ymax=1e3,
grid=both,
xmode=log,
%ymode=log,
thick,
y label style={at={(axis description cs:0.2,0.5)}},
restrict y to domain=-50:50,
]
\addplot[blue, domain=1:1e12, samples=500, smooth] {1/(1/(2*pi*x*1e-6)+(2*pi*x*1e-9))};
\addplot[red, domain=1:1e12, samples=500, smooth] {1/(1/(2*pi*x*1e-6)-(2*pi*x*1e-9))};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


You might want the absolute value on a logarithmic scale like this:
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
width=14cm, height=12cm,
xlabel={Frequency (Hz)},
xmin=1, xmax=1e12,
ymin=1e-6, ymax=1e3,
grid=both,
xmode=log,
ymode=log,
thick,
y label style={at={(axis description cs:0.2,0.5)}},
]
\addplot[blue, domain=1:1e12, samples=500, smooth] {1/(1/(2*pi*x*1e-6)+(2*pi*x*1e-9))};
\addplot[red, domain=1:1e12, samples=500, smooth] {abs(1/(1/(2*pi*x*1e-6)-(2*pi*x*1e-9)))};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



Right! This works. I didnt use the proper formula for the function, I forgot to use the abs() on the code.
